# me sale este error en pantalla Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in

Tags: php, html, mysql, json

```
Tengo este codigo en php que me permite cargar entre otras cosas una foto de un producto, pero me arroja un error de codificacion con respecto al almacenamiento de la foto,pero no logro dar con el error.
```

el input tipo file tiene el mismo nombre que donde se recibe la informacion, aunque si me almacena el resto de la informacion,solamente no me almacena la imagen, solamente me arroja el warning y ejecuta el query normalmente.

```css
<div id="addProductModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <form name="add_product" id="add_product" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="modal-header">      
      <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar Producto</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">     
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Código</label>
       <input type="text" name="code"  id="code" class="form-control" required>
       
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Producto</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Categoría</label>
       <input type="text" name="category" id="category" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Stock</label>
       <input type="number" name="stock" id="stock" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Precio</label>
       <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" required>
      </div> 

      <div class="photo">
       <label for="foto">Foto</label>
             <div class="prevPhoto">
              <span class="delPhoto notBlock">X</span>
              <label for="foto"></label>
             </div>
             <div class="upimg">
              <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto">
              </div>
             <div id="form_alert"></div>
      </div>
         
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Guardar datos">
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

```html
<?php
 if (empty($_POST['name'])){
  $errors[] = "Ingresa el nombre del producto.";
 } elseif (!empty($_POST['name'])){
 require_once ("../conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
 // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
    if( isset($_FILES['foto']) ) {
        $foto = $_FILES['foto'];
        
     
    $foto = $_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"];
 $nombrefoto  = $_FILES["foto"]["name"];
//este es el archivo que añadiremosal campo blob
   $foto  = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
  //lo comvertimos en binario antes de guardarlo
  }

    $prod_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["code"],ENT_QUOTES)));
 $prod_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["name"],ENT_QUOTES)));
 $prod_ctry = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["category"],ENT_QUOTES)));
 $foto=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(file_get_contents($_FILES["foto"],ENT_QUOTES)));
 $stock = intval($_POST["stock"]);
 
 $price = floatval($_POST["price"]);

 

 // REGISTER data into database
 
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblprod(id, prod_code, prod_name, prod_ctry, prod_qty,foto, price) VALUES (NULL,'$prod_code','$prod_name','$prod_ctry','$stock','$foto','$price')";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    // if product has been added successfully
    if ($query) {
        $messages[] = "El producto ha sido guardado con éxito.";
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Lo sentimos, el registro falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.";
    }
  
 } else 
 {
  $errors[] = "desconocido.";
 }

if (isset($errors)){
   
   ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
     <strong>Error!</strong> 
     <?php
      foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
       }
      ?>
   </div>
   <?php
   }
   if (isset($messages)){
    
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
      <?php
       foreach ($messages as $message) {
         echo $message;
        }
       ?>
    </div>
    <?php
   }
?>
```

Comment: ¿De qué tipo de dato es tu campo foto? También veo que intentas guardar el array  $_POST en ese campo de tu base de datos y eso no es posible, ¿por qué tendrías que hacerlo o qué es lo que realmente queires guardar en tu base de datos? ¿La ruta? ¿Un archivo blob? ¿Qué necesitas?

Comment: es un longblob el campo de la foto y quiero guardar el tipo blob, es que en mis formularios por procedimientos si lo almacena bien, pero con este estilo no me lo permite guardar.

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($_FILES);` para ver qué es lo que hay realmente. Parece que no hay nada en la clave `foto` y por eso el error.

Comment: a ver, creo que entonces te faltó ponerle el tmp a tu $_FILE, prueba con $_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"]

Comment: no me funciono niguna de las dos recomendaciones.